# sorting a structure array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a structure  with two fields 'word' and 'number' and need to find a way to create new structure arrays for all the elements that have the same number.
An example of the strucure array could be:

```
a=struct('word',{'meercat','window','lemon','dog','cheese','penguin'},'number',{4,2,2,2,2,1})
```

I am trying to split the structure into separate arrays for words of the same number, e.g.:

```
a1=struct('word',{'meercat'},'number',{4})
a2=struct('word',{'window','lemon','dog','cheese'},'number',{2,2,2,2})
a2=struct('word',{'penguin'},'number',{1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the numbers and use logical indexing:

```
a = struct('word'  , {'meercat','window','lemon','dog','cheese','penguin'}, ...
           'number', {4,2,2,2,2,1})

% extract numbers
num = [a(:).number]

% indexing
a1 = a(num == 4)
a2 = a(num == 2)
a3 = a(num == 1)
```

**you can automize it:**

```
sortedStructs = arrayfun(@(x) a(num == x), unique(num),'uni',0)
```

it returns a cell array with one struct for each number:

```
sortedStructs{1} =

      word: 'penguin'
    number: 1

sortedStructs{2} =

1x4 struct array with fields:

    word              
    number

sortedStructs{3} =

      word: 'meercat'
    number: 4
```

---

Add the `'stable'` property to `unique` if you want to keep the original order: `unique(num,'stable')`.